# Component XComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Tags: angular

i create a route . when i use this code : `{path: ':id' , component: RecipeDetailComponent}`

it show me this error :

> Error: Component RecipeDetailComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

i import `RecipeDetailComponent` in `app.module` and `AppModuleRouting` :

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RecipeComponent } from './recipe/recipe.component';
import { RecipeListComponent } from './Recipe/recipe-list/recipe-list.component';
import { RecipeDetailComponent } from './Recipe/recipe-detail/recipe-detail.component';
import { ShopingListComponent } from './shoping-list/shoping-list.component';
import { ShopingEditComponent } from './shoping-list/shoping-edit/shoping-edit.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { DropDownDirective } from './Directive/drop-down.directive';
import { RecipeItemComponent } from './recipe/recipe-list/recipe-item/recipe-item.component';
import {RecipeService} from './recipe/service/recipe.service';
import {ShopingService} from './shoping-list/service/shoping.service';
import {AppModuleRouting} from './routing/app-module-routing';
import { RecipeStartComponent } from './recipe/recipe-start/recipe-start.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RecipeComponent,
    RecipeListComponent,
    RecipeDetailComponent,
    ShopingListComponent,
    ShopingEditComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    DropDownDirective,
    RecipeItemComponent,
    RecipeStartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppModuleRouting
  ],
  providers: [RecipeService, ShopingService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {RecipeComponent} from '../recipe/recipe.component';
import {ShopingListComponent} from '../shoping-list/shoping-list.component';
import {RecipeStartComponent} from '../recipe/recipe-start/recipe-start.component';
import {RecipeDetailComponent} from '../recipe/recipe-detail/recipe-detail.component';

const appRouts: Routes = [
  { path: '' , redirectTo: '/app-recipe' , pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'app-recipe' , component: RecipeComponent , children: [
    {path: '', component: RecipeStartComponent},
    {path: ':id' , component: RecipeDetailComponent}
  ]},
  { path: 'app-shoping-list' , component: ShopingListComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRouts)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppModuleRouting {
}
```

and it show me this warning in firebug :

> ./src/app/Recipe/recipe-detail/recipe-detail.component.css
>   There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
>   This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
>   Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
>   * E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\node_modules\exports-loader\index.js?module.exports.toString()!E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\node_modules\css-loader\index.js?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js!E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\src\app\Recipe\recipe-detail\recipe-detail.component.css
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\src\app\Recipe\recipe-detail\recipe-detail.component.ts
>   * E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\node_modules\exports-loader\index.js?module.exports.toString()!E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\node_modules\css-loader\index.js?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\node_modules\postcss-loader\index.js!E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\src\app\recipe\recipe-detail\recipe-detail.component.css
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!E:\AngularTraning\RecipeFinal\src\app\recipe\recipe-detail\recipe-detail.component.ts

how can i solve this problem ?

**update**

Detail.ts :

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {RecipeModel} from '../model/recipe-model';
import {RecipeService} from '../service/recipe.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-detail',
  templateUrl: './recipe-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-detail.component.css']
})
export class RecipeDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() recipe: RecipeModel;
  id: number;
  constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService ,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
        this.recipe = this.recipeService.GetRecipe(this.id);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Kianoosh Jan, show us the content of receipe-details.component.ts

Comment: @Milad jan . i update the question